# How to tell System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer to only serialize base class?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, base-class

I have an array of objects of my base class `MyBase`. Some of these objects are instances of derived classes so when I try to serialize this array using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` it fails with complaints about the derived classes: *System.InvalidOperationException: The type DerivedClass was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.*

I don't want to serialize the derived classes, and I definitely don't want to put `[XmlIgnore()]` in the derived classes (or `[XmlInclude()]` in the base class, for that matter)!

Is there a way to tell `XmlSerializer` to **only serialize the base** for a member such as this one?

```
[XmlElement("Items")]
public MyBase[] Items
{
    get
    {
        return items.ToArray();
    }
    set 
    {
        items = new HashSet<MyBase>(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you pass in the type to the xmlserializer constructor?

Comment: I did try this, but couldn't get it to work:

    List<Type> derivedTypes = new List<Type>();
    foreach (MyBase item in items)
    {
        derivedTypes.Add(item.GetType());
    }

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootItem), derivedTypes.ToArray());

Answer (score 1):

You could do a Linq query on the items collection, filtering on type:

```
[XmlElement("Items")]
public MyBase[] Items
{
    get
    {
        return items.Where(item => item.GetType() == typeof(MyBase)).ToArray();
    }
    set 
    {
        items = new HashSet<MyBase>(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: .OfType<T> and/or .Cast<T> may come in handy too

Comment: Thanks. Can't get it to work though. The serializer keeps skipping my items.

Comment: Hmm, I thought you wanted it to only serialize the non-derived `MyBase` items? This bit of Linq intentionally skips items that are not exactly the type of `MyBase`.

Comment: Upon further thought, you could implement a deep copy constructor (or implement IClonable) on your `MyBase` class, and just do `return items.Select(item => new MyBase(item)).ToArray();` in the get accessor for Items. If you don't want to edit your `MyBase` class, you could implement one of the many external deep copy methods available via reflection.

Comment: As long as I don't have to do extra work in each derived class I'm happy. If I put all the serialization stuff in the base class and then populate a list of derived types to be fed to the XmlSerializer constructor, it works. Is this a similar approach to yours?